# New version of iPhone APP using another computer

Tags: iphone

I need to submit a new version of an application for iphone. The current version was created and submitted by the customer and I was hired to create the new version.

When I try to validate the application the following message appears:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s41/sh/a767446e-6b42-40eb-a346-222e82661d39/0ab7fe259ebb267a166c5e034955576f

I think, I have to generate a new distribution certificate. I've got access to the customer's account(itunes connect), but I'm afraid to revoke the current certificate and give problems in the app that is for sale in the app store.

How should I proceed? Revoke the certificate and create another in my machine?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to export your developer profile (i.e. all your provisioning profiles and the keys) through the Xcode Organizer.
In the Organizer under Devices tab select Developer Identity (to be found in the Teams section) and export it (you'll be prompted for a password). Transfer this file to the new system and import, your identity should be set up on the new system after that.